# Separate Celery Workers Incorrectly Cross-Routing

Tags: python, docker, celery

I'm building a service with two different celery workers for two different tasks. I'm having issues where tasks set for one worker are going to another, resulting in the error `Received unregistered task of type 'create_celery_test'`

Worker 1:

```
celery_app = Celery(__name__, backend='redis://localhost:6379/0', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@celery_app.task(bind=True, name="create_worker1_job")
def create_worker1_job(self, args):
    # stuff happens here
```

Worker 2:

```
celery_app = Celery(__name__, backend='redis://localhost:6379/0', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@celery_app.task(bind=True, name="create_worker2_job")
def create_worker2_job(self, args):
    # different stuff happens here
```

Docker compose:

```
  worker_1:
    build: ./app
    command: celery -A app.worker1.celery_app worker --loglevel=info --logfile=backend/logs/worker1.log --pool=solo -n worker1@%h
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker_2:
    build: ./app
    command: celery -A app.worker2.celery_app worker --loglevel=info --logfile=backend/logs/worker2.log -n worker2@%h
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:7
```

When other code calls `create_worker2_job`, the function call actually is sent to worker 1, which doesn't have that task registered, resulting in an error. The cross-routing confusion doesn't always happen, and is somewhat random. Each worker is in a separate docker container, separate app, and given a separate name.

How do I guarantee tasks are routed to the correct worker?